# Selectively add "tables" to multiple tabs (<div>) using HTML

Tags: javascript, css, html

I've a C++ application, which writes "tables" into a HTML File. 
I've given implementation to the API()s in such a way that all tabls are written 1 below another, using simple HTML. (I had HTML into C++ strings & then write them to a file).

```
for(int i=0;i<totalNumOfTables;++i)
{
    WriteTableName(tabName);
    WriteTableHeader(vector_of_strings_header);
    while(!all_rows_are-filled())
    {
        writeRowsToTable(vector_of_strings_row);
    }
    MarkTableEnd();
}
```

> However, i want to write these tables into 4 tabs (based on the
>   category to which each table belongs to) within the same HTML file, so
>   that i can categorize the tables.

I understood  from "[this link](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_tabs.asp) that  tags can be used to create tab in HTML.

**However, how do I create/add HTML tables selectively in each HTML tab ?**

I'm very new to HTML, javascript, hence kindly go easy on me.

Comment: This is not a C++ question. The fact that you generate your HTML with C++ is as relevant as the OS its running on and the breakfast you had this morning ;)

Comment: @YSC has a good point - before you write any C++, you might want to write your expected HTML by hand to check that it works like you intend.

Comment: Breakfast.... Holy cow! No wonder I've been hungry all day.

Answer (score 0):

First Step is to create tabs HTML

```
function FirstCallthisMethd() {
    var tabsHtml = '<div class="tab">';

    for (i = 0; i < totalNumOfTables; ++i) {
        tabsHtml += '<button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, totalNumOfTables[i].TableName>totalNumOfTables[i].TableName</button>'
    }

    tabsHtml += '</div>'

    CreateTabs(tabsHtml);

}
```

Now Add tabcontent over your tables with Writetabcontent method:

```
for (i = 0; i < totalNumOfTables; ++i) {

    Writetabcontent('<div id=totalNumOfTables[i].TableName class="tabcontent">')
    WriteTableName(tabName);
    WriteTableHeader(vector_of_strings_header);
    while (!all_rows_are - filled()) {
        writeRowsToTable(vector_of_strings_row);
    }
    MarkTableEnd();
    MarkTabContentEnd('</div>')
}
```